# Mono Repository with multiple services and unique versioning

Tags: git, versioning, gitversion

I am looking to see if there is a way to unique version microservices in a Mono Repository.

Using GitVersion with Multiple Repositories, the microservice version is unique.

Using GitVersion with Mono Repositories, the microservices will share the same version for the whole of the repo.

Is there a way to get the Mono Repository Model to follow the Multiple Repository model's versioning style?

Comment: We just bumped into this problem. @jason-h did you solve this problem in any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something that has been discussed, but the outcome was a decision that this is not something that GitVersion is going to do.  GitVersion has always been designed to assert a single version number for a single repository, and I don’t see that changing in the future.

Comment: Fair enough, alternatives to GitVersion that can accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I am aware of some alternatives to GitVersion, for example NerdBank.GitVersioining, Bumpy, ZeroToNine, but to the best of my knowledge they won’t help in this scenario either.

Comment: In the end, I ended up splitting up our microservices into multiple repositories.  GitVersion is based on the Git History and tags so no matter how hard you try, be it by hiding parts of the repo or trying to limit things to a specific folder, it always resulted in very odd behaviour.

Comment: When you say "odd behaviour" you are really trying to use GitVersion in a way that it wasn't intended, so really the behaviour is probably "working as intended".  Glad you were able to get this sorted out though!

Comment: You are correct, the behaviour was working as intended but not as I wanted it too.